# Enable or disable based on model and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do one of two things with my form.

1. Disable all fields if a new model instance is passed in and then react to user input as items are checked.
2. Enable/disable the fields as defined in an existing model that is passed in.

All the rails variables are being passed in fine.. Its my jquery thats jacked.

My Jquery looks like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var shipping = function() {
  if($(".<%= type %>-check").is(':checked')) {
    $('.<%= type %>').prop( "disabled", false );}
  else{$('.<%= type %>').prop( "disabled", true );}
}

var free = function() {
  if($('.free-check').is(':checked')) {
    $('.free-amount').prop( "disabled", false );}
  else{$('.free-amount').prop( "disabled", true );}
}

 if <%= shipping_shop.shipping_speed %> == 0 {
  $('.free-amount').prop( "disabled", true );
  $('.<%= type %>').prop( "disabled", true );  
 }
 else {
   shipping();
   free();
 }

$('.<%= type %>-check').on('change', shipping);
$('.free-check').on('change', free);
});
```

What I want is to disable the fields if `shipping_speed == 0` which means the shop hasn't been setup yet and enable the form to react to user input. Otherwise I want the form to reflect what's in the DB. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need parentheses around your `if` condition

```
 if (<%= shipping_shop.shipping_speed %> == 0) {
  $('.free-amount').prop( "disabled", true );
  $('.<%= type %>').prop( "disabled", true );  
 }
 else {
   shipping();
   free();
 }
```

Also I use `.removeProp()` to enable the input but that may just be a coding style choice.

```
$('.free-amount').prop('disabled', 'true');
$('.free-amount').removeProp('disabled');
```